# Is there a conflict between an identity column and the recommendation to use the smallest value possible for a database table column?

Tags: t-sql, identity-column

I find myself using "bigint" (64-bit integer) for all my row identity columns, not because I ever expect the table to hold a number of rows in excess of a 32-bit integer's max value, but because constantly adding and removing rows over time could cause the identity value to exceed that of a 32-bit integer, which I understand would cause an overflow error and prevent subsequent insert statements from succeeding.

Aside from adding special logic to periodically "defrag" or reseed an identity column, is there any workaround for this?  Or should I just keep using "bigint" to be safe?  Is it even safe?

By my calculations, my desktop would take ~1826 years just to increment an integer from 0 to 2^64 in a tight/infinite loop, let alone insert and delete that many database rows.  Then again, a computer a thousand times faster than mine could do it in a year or two.  Could this be a good case for utilizing 128-bit uniqueidentifiers as database row keys?

Comment: Just wondering how would the performance be on such huge tables! Imagine one good self join and the machine will go in smoke :) My point is that there are other problems than just the key size for this kind of database.

Comment: I'm not talking about large tables, as I said, it's not that I expect the number of rows to exceed the limit of a 32-bit identifier; I was saying that as an incrementing identity column, if one was to insert and delete even a single row more than 2 billion times, all those identity values would get eaten up, and then an overflow would occur.  At that point, the table may still only contain a handful of rows with ID values like 0, 10, and 2^31-1, but you couldn't insert new rows until you defrag the values and reseed it.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I got your point, I guess it is valid in many real-life applications. I wonder how many systems faced this or about to....Sounds as terrible as the Y2K thing.

Comment: Exactly.  It just seems to me like an identity column is a special case, because it imposes a limit on the number of inserts you can perform, regardless of how many rows are actually in a table at one time.  The value of a 32-bit integer is a limit that could realistically be broken, possibly even many times, within the lifespan of a high performance application.  I started wondering if even a 64-bit integer is large enough after doing the math, and it seems a 128-bit integer may be the most future-proof.  Perhaps we may as well just accept using random GUIDs as row ids and optimize for it.

Comment: I came across this post that mentions using a negative value as a starting point to give a longer life span for the Identity: http://sqlfool.com/2011/01/identity-columns-are-you-nearing-the-limits/

Comment: Well, a **tight loop** is a highly speculative and non-realistic example - and even with the fastest disk I/O subsystems, actually **inserting** data into a disk-based database will be on the order of 1000 to 10'000 times slower than just incrementing a counter. Even with a computer a thousand times faster than your current one, I'm pretty sure you wouldn't be able to survive long enough to see a `BIGINT IDENTITY` overflow ......

Comment: A tight loop was used as an upper bound; that is all.  FYI, someone achieved 750,000 inserts a second with 48 cores and 4 fusion-IO cards two years ago: http://blog.kejser.org/2011/10/05/boosting-insert-speed-by-generating-scalable-keys/  Based on that value alone, it would take a system only one million times faster to overflow a big int in just over 9 months of activity.  We don't know what the future holds, but IMO these numbers will EASILY be blown away in my lifetime.  I'm switching to GUIDs now.